# Laravel Client Switching Functionality

Tags: laravel, eloquent, associations, laravel-7

I am new to laravel and do not have much experience with using ORM. I am building a system in which I need build functionality to allow user to switch clients with another user. I am not sure what is the best method to achieve this.

Currently client belongs to user, do I need another association for client and user model using different foreign key ?

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Even though a client can only have one user switch request I would like to track all the requests so for example if user A makes request to switch client Test with user B and then make another request to switch the same client with user C I would like to soft delete the first record and create new record for new request. Once the other user accepts the request we change the primary key for client Test in the clients table. Will this be a One To Many / Many To Many relationship ?

What table naming conventions do I need to follow ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to temporarily switch clients for one user to another. What you should do is have another table say `switched-clients` that holds records for the switches with columns `user1` and `user2`. When you want to retrieve clients, your controller checks this table first and if the record exists `where('user1', 'user A')` (according to your example), then you retrieve the clients for user2.

Comment: It is not a temporarily switch clients for one user to another. When user2 accepts user1 request to switch client Test for example. I need to update the foreign key in the clients table to user2.